# Depth of a grid map when represented as a tree

Tags: algorithm, search

I have a nxn grid map. I want to represent this as a tree where each node is a block in the grid and each edge is the movement(left,right,up,and down) from one block to another. I want to know, if this grid was represented as a tree, what would be its depth.

I came up this formula but I am not sure if this is correct:

Since there are at most 4 movements possible from each block, at each level t of the tree there are at most 4^t nodes. So total number of nodes in tree is at most
4^0 + 4^1 + 4^2+.....4^d where d is the depth of the tree and this is greater than or equal to n^2(actual number of blocks in the grid).

When I solve this equation(by taking sum of the geometric series on the left side and then taking log base 4 on both sides) I get the following result:

d >= log(3n^2 + 1) - 1    (log is base 4)

But this still does not give me the exact depth of the tree.

Is there a way to find exact depth of the tree?

Comment: The depth is one, the grid itself, because the branches cross each other.  One branch going right is the same as another branch going left, etc.

Comment: The way this is currently described, this sounds like a graph, not a tree.

Comment: s_123, your calculation seems to assume that when you start wherever you do and take your four possible steps from each block to a neighbour, the results never overlap. But of course they do; e.g., if you go north then east from somewhere, you get to the same place as if you go east and then north. I think you need to be a bit more precise about exactly what tree you're constructing -- and when you do, I think it may be pretty obvious what its depth is.